# Difference between useState and props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand the difference between the following two approaches in a simple example where the button color is changed when there is a mouse hover event.

First approach using props:

```
function over(props) {
  props.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
};

function out(props){
  props.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
};

return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1>{headingText}</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" />
    <button onMouseOver={over} onMouseOut={out}>Submit</button>
  </div>
);
```

Second approach using useState:

```
const [isMouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false);
 
function handleMouseOver() {
  setMouseOver(true);
};

function handleMouseOut() {
  setMouseOver(false);
};
  
return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1>{headingText}</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="What's your name?" />
    <button
      onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
      onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
      style={{ backgroundColor: isMouseOver ? "black" : "white"}}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

I can see the same behavior is accomplished, but I would like to understand if technically there is any difference between these two, and if these are both valid then perhaps the first one should not be used?

Comment: The first example code is a pure javascript approach, whereas the second one uses the React framework to complete the same task. PS: the variable `prop` in the first example is an event object. If you want to implement your solution using the React framework, you should not use the first approach only. If you choose not to use the React framework to implement your solution, you have to use the first approach.

Comment: Tangential: I'd name event handlers' parameter `event` since it's an event *(not properties)* and `props` has a generally-accepted meaning in React.

Comment: The first approach (a) uses the DOM to store application state, and (b) modifies the DOM directly. App state should be maintained separately from its representation in the DOM *(also makes it easier to query/manipulate)*. Simple DOM manipulation should be handled via default React rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the advices and insights, it is much clear now.

Answer (score 0):

1. **State and UI Update**:
   When you want to update something on the UI based on changes in data (like a counter increment), React provides a mechanism to manage and track such changes. React components can have their own internal state which holds data that can influence the rendering of the component.
2. **useState Hook**:
   The `useState` hook is a feature in React that lets you add state to your functional components. It provides a way to declare a piece of state in your component along with a function to update that state.

   ```
   const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
   ```

   In this example, `counter` is the state value, and `setCounter` is the function you use to update `counter`.
3. **Updating State and Triggering UI Updates**:
   When you want to update the state, you use the provided state update function (`setCounter` in this case). React's `useState` and other state management hooks are built in a way that when you call the update function, React knows that the state has changed and will trigger a re-render of the component.

   ```
   const handleIncrement = () => {
     setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
   };
   ```

   This function takes the previous state (`prevCounter`) as an argument and returns the new state value (previous value + 1).
4. **Using State in UI**:
   Once you've updated the state using `setCounter` (or other similar state update functions), React will automatically re-render the component, and any parts of the UI that depend on the state (in this case, the value of `counter`) will be updated accordingly.

So, your recommendation of using the `useState` hook to manage state and trigger UI updates is indeed a widely accepted and modern approach in React development.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is just using regular functions, with arguments (not to be confused with props, which is the argument to a component's render function).

The second approach gives you access to the logical state of your component, and renders the view from that. Interaction lead to changing that internal state, and then re-rendering what needs to be re-rendered. The state of your component can be local, or be a view/lens of a global state.

The first approach doesn't give you access to the logical state of your component. That state has to be deduced by reading it, at a local level. You can't have access to said state anywhere without propagating back up yourself. It also leaves you with the hard task of intelligently managing DOM state updates.